# Solr 5 Integration Tests with Maven

Tags: maven, solr, integration-testing, solr5

For Solr 5 the developers have announced that the Solr server will [soon be a standalone server](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar) as opposed to a webapp as it has been in the past.

My question is about how I would spin up a clean Solr instance for my integration tests, considering the fact that Solr is not a webapp anymore (actually, currently it still is, but this will likely change soon).

Having it as a webapp was quite convenient for integration tests. We could just use the cargo-maven plugin to deploy the war and copy over some configuration files. What would my options be for a standalone Solr server?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: a project [1] which used Solr 4.x and a huge integration suite managed by Maven and Cargo. After migrating to Solr 5.3.1, I had to change my approach.

Actually it is very simple: Each (TestCase) class should extends

```
org.apache.solr.SolrJettyTestBase
```

The servlet engine is not automatically started, it's up to you. Instead, there's an @AfterClass method that (in case Jetty has been started) stop it at the end of the test methods.

You can find a working example here [2].

---

[1] https://github.com/agazzarini/SolRDF
[2] https://github.com/agazzarini/SolRDF/blob/master/solrdf/solrdf-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/gazzax/labs/solrdf/integration/IntegrationTestSupertypeLayer.java